# 'Button' object has no attribute 'response' discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets, discord, discord.py

**Hello
I'm creating a bot that connects Discord to Google Sheets to make room reservations.
I have an error that I can't understand if anyone has already had it I wouldn't say no to adie :)

I explain to you. When we do the "!reserver" command a button appears and when I click on it I get an interaction error.
I'll put the logs after the source code.**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Button, View, Select
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


def get_gspread_client():
  scope = [
      "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
  ]
  creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
      "reservation-salles-brique-901c122a60ee.json", scope)
  return gspread.authorize(creds)


def get_room_names():
  client = get_gspread_client()
  spreadsheet = client.open('Réservation des salles')
  worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet('Nom des salles')
  room_names = [
      item['Nom de la salle'] for item in worksheet.get_all_records()
  ]
  return room_names


class RoomSelect(Select):

  def __init__(self):
    room_names = get_room_names()
    options = [discord.SelectOption(label=room) for room in room_names]
    super().__init__(placeholder='Sélectionnez une salle...', options=options)

  async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    self.view.room = self.values[0]
    self.view.stop()


class TimeInputView(View):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.room = None

  @discord.ui.button(label="Réserver", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
  async def reserve_button(self, button: discord.ui.Button,
                           interaction: discord.Interaction):
    try:
      if self.room:
        # ...
        await interaction.response.send(
            f'Réservation confirmée pour {self.room} dans la feuille "Réservation".'
        )
      else:
        await interaction.response.send('Veuillez sélectionner une salle.')
    except gspread.exceptions.APIError as e:
      logging.error(f"Erreur lors de l'interaction avec Google Sheets : {e}")
    except discord.errors.DiscordException as e:
      logging.error(f"Erreur lors de l'interaction avec Discord : {e}")


# ...


@bot.command()
async def reserver(ctx):
  view = TimeInputView()
  await ctx.send(
      "Veuillez sélectionner la salle que vous souhaitez réserver :",
      view=view)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'Bot connecté comme {bot.user}')



bot.run(
    'TOKEN')
```

Logs Errors:

```
ERROR    discord.ui.view Ignoring exception in view <TimeInputView timeout=180.0 children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.success: 3> url=None disabled=False label='Réserver' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Bot-reservation-discord/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "/home/runner/Bot-reservation-discord/main.py", line 67, in reserve_button
    await interaction.response.send('Veuillez sélectionner une salle.')
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'
ERROR:discord.ui.view:Ignoring exception in view <TimeInputView timeout=180.0 children=1> for item <Button style=<ButtonStyle.success: 3> url=None disabled=False label='Réserver' emoji=None row=None>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Bot-reservation-discord/.pythonlibs/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "/home/runner/Bot-reservation-discord/main.py", line 67, in reserve_button
    await interaction.response.send('Veuillez sélectionner une salle.')
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'
```

TY <3

I would like that when I click on the button it displays the selection of rooms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is `interaction.response.send_message("YOUR_MESSAGE")`

Here is a quick example:

```
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Test",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="my_custom_button")
    async def testbutton(self,interaction:discord.Interaction,button:discord.ui.Button):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Testing...")

@bot.tree.command(name='testbutton')
async def testbutton(interaction:discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(view=MyView())
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :) The thing is, I would like it to display the list of rooms. And I have the impression that the problem comes from AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'response'

Comment: Yes, it is. When you declare the button and the interaction, you should follow the order that I provided in the example. So `async def reserve_button(self, button: discord.ui.Button,interaction: discord.Interaction):`
should be: `async def reserve_button(self, interaction:discord.Interaction,button: discord.ui.Button):`

Comment: Jezz thank you I love you